# "Cannot use import statement outside a module" without "type: module"

Tags: node.js, npm, import

I've NodeJS app whit many file like this:

```
import '@babel/polyfill'
import app from './app'
```

`./app` is a js file: `app.js` and `@babel/polyfill` is a npm package

When I try to start my app with `npm run dev` i got this error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I've seen that you can use `"type": "module"` on package.json to solve the problem

But this causes another problem:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module './app' imported from /boot.js
```

I have many file that import modules and other files like that so i can't change them all

How do I keep the two type fo import?

Answer (score 0):

If you only import babel like that you can setup babel for global import

This is `.babelrc` file on root folder:

```
{
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```